# array data insert in laravel

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I am getting this kind of data from the database in array form.

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1434
  #items: array:4 [
    0 => 20
    1 => 21
    2 => 22
    3 => 19
  ]
}
```

I want to insert the this array data through the controller For each array element.

```
 foreach($plucked as $data){
    $attendant_data = new EmployeeAttendant();
    $attendant_data->user_id = $data;
    $attendant_data->date = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $attendant_data->time = Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s');
    $attendant_data->present = '0';
    $attendant_data->save();
 }
```

Data is being inserted only for the first array element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just prepare the data and insert it.

```
$insertableAttendant = [];
foreach($plucked as $data){
    $attendant_data = [];
    $attendant_data['user_id'] = $data;
    $attendant_data['date'] = Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d');
    $attendant_data['time'] = Carbon::now()->format('H:i:s');
    $attendant_data['present'] = '0';
    $insertableAttendant[] = $attendant_data;
 }
EmployeeAttendant::insert($insertableAttendant);
```